# Unable to Connect to MySQL Database on Forpsi Hosting from Local Machine

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, remote-access

I recently purchased a domain and hosting on "www.forpsi.com" for a client's website project. While I have experience with AWS hosting, I'm relatively new to Forpsi hosting. My client required me to use Forpsi, so I opted for it. As part of the hosting package, I also have access to a MySQL database service.

I'm currently working on developing the backend API for an admin page on the website, and to do that, I need to test the database connection from my local development machine. Unfortunately, I've encountered connection issues when trying to access the MySQL database on Forpsi hosting.

Here are the steps I've taken and the errors I've encountered:

**MySQL Client Attempt:**

```bash
mysql -h xxx.forpsi.com -u xxxxx -p
```

**Error Message:**

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.forpsi.com:3306' (113)
```

**PHP Script Attempt:**

```php
<?php
$hostname = 'xxx.forpsi.com';
$username = 'xxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$database = 'xxx';

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

echo 'Connected to the database successfully!';
$mysqli->close();
```

**Error Message:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No route to host in /tmp/AbhiAtx/t.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /tmp/AbhiAtx/t.php(7): mysqli->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /tmp/AbhiAtx/t.php on line 7
```

I've double-checked my database credentials, and they appear to be correct. Is there something specific I need to configure on Forpsi hosting to allow remote connections to the MySQL database? Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible they won't allow remote connections at all, some hosts don't. If they do, its likely you have to whitelist the IP you want to connect from. If they give you cPanel you cab probably configure it there. But why do you need to? Why not just develop the API locally, connecting to a local database? Then deploy the code and DB to the hosted server when you want to go live.

Answer (score -3):

Try to verify the accessibility of a specific hostname or IP address, you can use one of these methods or online tools like "ping," "traceroute," or website monitoring services to perform the checks.

Comment: I tried pinging the host it is working. No issue

Comment: is there any vpn?

Comment: No, I am not using any VPN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).